# Android camera2 surface with size 1920x1080 is not valid

Tags: android, camera2

I've implemented camera2 in my app and it is working on Nexus 6P and Nexus 5. Now I'm trying to test it on other devices, and the first one I tried on failed straight away. This is the error I get on HTC M7 running Lollipop:

```
Surface with size (w=1920, h=1080) and format 0x1 is not valid, 
size not in valid set: [1920x1088, 1440x1088, 1456x832, 1088x1088,
1280x720, 960x720, 960x544, 720x720, 800x480, 768x464, 720x480, 
768x432, 640x480, 544x544, 576x432, 640x384, 640x368, 480x480, 
480x320, 384x288, 352x288, 320x240, 240x160, 176x144]
```

Any suggestions what should I do in this case? I've tried calculating the nearest resolution to my `TextureView` (which is 1280x720) and resizing `TextureView` accordingly, but that doesn't look particularly nice - too much unused space... Didn't see this problem on this device using old camera and `SurfaceView`

EDIT:

The problem seems to be inside my `TextureView`. This is my code:

inside a controller I have:

```
 TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture,
            int width, int height) {
        startLollipopPreview(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture,
            int width, int height) {
        configureTransform(width,height);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
    }
};


 private void startLollipopPreview(int width, int height) {
    CameraProxy camera = getCurrentCamera();
    try {
        if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
        }
        mPreviewSize = camera
                .getOptimalPreviewSize((Activity) mContext,
                        camera.getSupportedPreviewSizes(
                                width, height), (double) width / height);
        mPreviewTexture.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        mPreviewTexture.getSurfaceTexture().setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.width,
                mPreviewSize.height);
        configureTransform(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        camera.setStateAndHandler(getCameraStateCallback(), mBackgroundHandler);
        camera.open();
    } catch (CameraHardwareException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, ".surfaceCreated() - Error opening camera", e);
        ((Activity) mContext).finish();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, ".surfaceCreated() - InterruptedException opening camera", e);
    }
}
```

`configureTransform()` looks exactly like the Camera2 google sample so I don't think the problem is in there.

inside my `TextureView` I have the following:

```
 public void setAspectRatio(int width, int height) {
    if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be negative.");
    }
    mRatioWidth = width;
    mRatioHeight = height;
    requestLayout();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    if (0 == mRatioWidth || 0 == mRatioHeight) {
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    } else {
        if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight) {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
            setLayoutParams(params);
            setMeasuredDimension(width, width * mRatioHeight / mRatioWidth);
        } else {
            setMeasuredDimension(height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight, height);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Inside onMeasure I had to change if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight) to if (width > height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to set the buffer size to a supported preview size:

```
textureView.getSurfaceTexture().setDefaultBufferSize(1280,720);
```

and then you can scale the TextureView so that it fits your screen, even if the preview size is smaller. The [Camera2Video](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video) sample has an example. Specifically look at `configureTransform` in [Camera2VideoFragment](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video/Camera2VideoFragment.java):

```
/**
 * Configures the necessary {@link android.graphics.Matrix} transformation to `mTextureView`.
 * This method should not to be called until the camera preview size is determined in
 * openCamera, or until the size of `mTextureView` is fixed.
 *
 * @param viewWidth  The width of `mTextureView`
 * @param viewHeight The height of `mTextureView`
 */
private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize || null == activity) {
        return;
    }
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
    float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
    float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
    if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
        bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
        matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        float scale = Math.max(
                (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                (float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
        matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
    }
    mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
}
```

Comment: Added the scaling bit, still getting the error message. Now with the new resolution that I'm calculating with increased aspect ratio tolerance, I'm getting a slightly different values in the error `Surface with size (w=1890, h=1080)...` - the rest of the message is the same

Comment: I think the problem is in my `TextureView`. I'm using the same code as in the sample to set aspect ratio and call `setMeasuredDimension` inside `onMeasure` but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

Comment: I think you might need to adjust the buffer size of the texture view as well. `textureView.getSurfaceTexture().setDefaultBufferSize( previewWidth, previewHeight );`

Comment: Did you use setDefaultBufferSize( 1280, 720 ) or one of the other listed supported sizes?

Comment: Another supported one - 1920x1088

Comment: I've updated the post with some code - maybe you can spot something there? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It doesn't crash - just gives an error and no preview. I've figured out how to make it work though, however I can't say I understand the behaviour. Inside `onMeasure` I need to change `if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight)` to `if (width > height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight)`

Comment: Hi, have you guys found this solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you facing change according to emulator/device that you testing the app.

**This error occurs when the devices compatible sizes for the dimension of the screen and the MediaRecorder settings are not matched**.

When the camera is open (`openCamera(int w, int h)` method) it's getting the sizes of supported resolutions by using `chooseOptimalSize(.... .....)` method. But before that, it will set `videoSize()`.

Try to Logcat to get what are the supported sizes and according to that set the `mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(w,h);`